# Trying to form submit with jquery, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying post form data to new window using jquery. But I failed.

My source code is like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" > </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function submit_with_jquery(){
     var $form = $("<form></form>");
     var $input = $("<input name='imgInput' />");
     $form.prop("target", "photo_top")
        .prop("method", "post")
        .prop("action", "/common/board/photoViewWindow.jsp")
        .append($input)
        .bind("submit", 
            function(){ 
                window.open('','photo_pop','width=720,height=530,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,left=50,top=50'); 
            } )
        .submit();
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="submit_with_jquery()" value="submit with jquery" />
 </body>
</html>
```

(*I edited and changed attr to prop, but) It shows just `about:blank`...

And then, I tried this code and succeeded.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function submit_with_tag(){
     window.open('','photo_pop','width=720,height=530,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,left=50,top=50');
    }      </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form id="tagForm" action="/common/board/photoViewWindow.jsp" target="photo_pop" onSubmit="submit_with_tag()">
        <input name="imgInput" type="hidden"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit with tag"/>
    </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

I think it work same, but jQuery code isn't.
 Why my first code not work? Where did I something wrong?

Comment: Especially with the latest version of jQuery, you should be using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: @Pointy: Do you think this is really relevant for the `target`, `method` and `action` *attributes*? I don't think those are handled different.

Comment: @Bergi well it's kind-of confusing to me too, but 1.9 seems to make it more clear that setting attributes and setting properties are two completely different things. On a newly-created element like this, I don't really know for sure what the story is, but personally I'll go with `.prop()` in all cases when, without jQuery, I'd directly use DOM node properties.

Comment: target, method and action ARE in the attribute set of the FORM tag, so using .attr() is completely ok. This is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `target` is `"photo_top"`, your opened window is named `'photo_pop'`?

Apart from that, Ajax might be a better option than your first method where you manually build the form elements only to submit them.